Error after migrating 14 to 15 in dependent project?
I have FrontDesk/FrontDesk.UserInterface project  have updated all the packages to Angular 15.You can check the screenshot below.

I executed the following command ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration, which automatically updated all components in the FrontDesk/FrontDesk.UserInterface.
Afterward, I attempted to build the FrontDesk/FrontDesk.UserInterface project. However, all the errors that were thrown pertained to Shared/Shared.UserInterface2 except for one error in FrontDesk/FrontDesk.UserInterface within angular-routing.module.ts.
When attempting to update Angular and Material packages,
Shared/Shared.UserInterface2 > ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15

I encountered following error: This command is not available when running cli outside workspace.
After some research, I discovered that the angular.json file is missing from this project. This is why I couldn't update the packages directly. Nonetheless, I was able to install Angular and Material 15 packages in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2.
I then executed a command ng install @angular/material:mdc-migration to migrate material components in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2.
I attempted to install material-mdc-migration and generate material:mdc-migration both failed.
After build FrontDesk/FrontDesk.UserInterface there most repetitive issues one is angular material theming error and mat-chip-list errors in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2 I have failed to resolve two repetitive issues.

How to resolve Angular/Material/Theming Error?  I tried to uninstall and reinstall material packages  in dependent project Shared.Shared.UserInterface2 but it didn't work and I was unable to find node_modules/@angular/material/theming folder.



How could I execute material-mdc-migration in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2? If its not possible then what should be my approach?


I assume once we were able to execute the material-mdc-migration command It would automatically resolve material related issues in Shared/Shared.UserInterfac2.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

This question is similar to: Can't find stylesheet to import. Angular 17. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (Note: That question is about Angular 17, but it should be the same problem and fix for your Angular 15 app)

Remove that import and try adapting your code to mimic the below working example.
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $theme-primary,
    accent: $theme-accent,
    warn: $theme-warn,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);

Stackblitz Demo

Could you please help with Question 2. How could I execute material-mdc-migration in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2? If its not possible then what should be my approach? Do I have to do it manually?

@RamAnugandula You definetly have a import @angular/material/theming in Shared/Shared.UserInterface2 on angular-material.scss, check your first screenshot, first run the migration, if it does not run, try replacing the import to suit the template in my answer, maybe it will resolve your issue, but migration should run fine in the library.
